# browser app unable to access loki.js

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I'm trying to use `loki.js` in a browser app. I included the following script in the HTML

```
<script src="./bower_components/lokijs/src/lokijs.js"></script>
```

However the following js code gave me `"unexpected token"` error

```
db = new loki('test');
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `lokijs.js` is actually getting loaded by the browser?

Comment: check if its loading properly. I can't find any other mistake

Comment: Thanks - I wonder what could cause lokijs.js not to load? I inserted this new fragment in working code; used "ls" shell in the same directory to make sure the path is correct.  I can't see the source file in Chrome Developers console.

Comment: Hi, author of LokiJS here. If you create a plunker / jsfiddle i could try and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following script in your app

```
<script src="./bower_components/lokijs/build/lokijs.min.js"></script>
```

and then in your JavaScript file, or in script tags

```
    var db = new loki('test.json');
    var children = db.addCollection('children');
    children.insert({name:'Sleipnir', legs: 8});
    console.log(children.get(1)); // returns Sleipnir
```